# Sass color lighten/darken function

Tags: css, sass

so I can not understand sass *lighten/darke*n [color function](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/modules/color).

I get it that it changes `hue`/`saturation`/`lightness` but how can I know what will be the *hex* value after I use this function?

what will be the output color of *lighten/darke*n?

Comment: Your question is to broad, please provide more details. What does your design spec look like? What are you plugging into the color function? What is the expected result that you are expecting?

Comment: so I get adobe xd design spec where I can see color list (hex values)
but some of the elements in design spec has colors (again hex) not from that list.
When I use lighten function and different percentages I find out that it is primary color that is lightened. So what I want is instead of introducing many colors, have less colors defined and instead use lighten/darken function to get other required colors.

Comment: Ok so you have a hex base (primary color) and you want to derive certain other hex colors (sub colors of primary color) by applying HSL (mostly L) to get the known sub colors (hex) in your specs, correct? And you don't have the amout of L you need to apply to get the sub color hex value, right?

Comment: @mahatmanich that's exactly what I need :)

Comment: Have you made a comparison of the HSL values of the Primary and Sub colors? E.g. plugged both hex colors in here: https://serennu.com/colour/hsltorgb.php ? Is only L changing? If only L is changing, I guess you are safe to use the primary color with different L, but if HS is different then I would save that color as a different hex, since it is a different color and not a derivative from the primary color.

Comment: @mahatmanich and if only L is different is there an appropriate way to know the percentage that should be lighten or I should use external tool/figure out that percentage by trial and error?

Comment: If L is the factor you will only see L changing. Lets say you have #B4D455 (primary) and #425214 (sub color) you will get HLS 75° 60% 58% for primary and 75° 60% 20% for sub.

Then color.adjust(#B4D455, $lightness: -38%) should give you #425214 or maybe the rgb values of #425214 ...

Comment: Sharing article related to the topic: https://www.sitelint.com/blog/sass-darken-and-lighten-functions-replace-with-color-adjust-in-visual-studio-code/

Answer (score 5):

Lighten and darken functions are in the process of being deprecated in Sass with the new module system. They did not scale colors in an expected manner and it has been recommended to stay away from them now. The sass:color module with color.adjust() is what you should be using now.

Before the recent module update I used my own functions that looked like this:

```
/// Incrementally lighten a color in a more effective way than with lighten()
/// @param {Color} $color - color to tint
/// @param {Number} $percentage - Percentage of white in the returned color
/// @return {Color} - The lightened color
@function tint($color, $percentage) {
  @return mix(#fff, $color, $percentage);
}

/// Incrementally darken a color in a more effective way than with darken()
/// @param {Color} $color - Color to shade
/// @param {Number} $percentage - Percentage of black in the returned color
/// @return {Color} - The darkened color
@function shade($color, $percentage) {
  @return mix(#000, $color, $percentage);
}
```

However now it is recommended to use the color module. Information on the color module is here: https://sass-lang.com/documentation/modules/color and a primer on the new module system can be found here: https://css-tricks.com/introducing-sass-modules/

Using the functions in the color module will provide more expected and predictable outputs, but if you need to know the exact hex code of the output color you can either figure out how to calculate that in your head, or you could use the @debug feature (https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/debug) or play around with a live compiler on a snippet of code.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for `@debug` to see the final value of the output!

https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/debug

Comment: does that mean I have each time to debug to figure out what should be the percentage? As I have a design specs and I need a specific hex value...

Comment: What does your design spec use? RGB HSL or HEX, or a combination thereof?
https://serennu.com/colour/hsltorgb.php calculates all of these depending on one another ...